# Interpreting trucker lingo

Tags: meaning

I am translating a text from English, and I have a problem with two expressions. I was not able to find anything on the internet, and I'm not sure I understand the meaning of them.

Basically these are instructions for truck drivers:

> **Boot still** has to be at least 1.10m for deliveries. Truck load must be
>   at least 2.35m wide and 2.30m high. This is the usual size of a 7.5t
>   truck or larger vehicle. Total vehicle height must not exceed 4m.

I know what a *boot* is, but what exactly is *boot still*? Is it the height of the boot loading platform?

And then my second problem:

> Unloading of swap bodies **with a pass-through loading provision** is not
>   possible.

I know what *swap bodies* are, but I don't get the second half of the sentence.

Comment: The "still" should just be the normal adverb (or well, at least it seems that way to me out of context) after something "unusual" has been stated in a prior sentence.

Comment: thanks, that is what I thought, but it is a bit odd. And do you have any idea about the second one?

Comment: I'm not sure what a pass-through is in this setting, but I guess in whatever scenario that's supposed to mean, there's an allowance for loading? Not completely sure though.

Comment: If you happen to know someone in the trucking industry, I would recommend contacting them instead. Some of these might be industry terms that aren't widely known.

Comment: OK, thanks. Well my understanding of it is that the swap body can be allowed to stay "with the truck" during unloading/loading, but the actual swap body stays untouched.

Comment: A pass-through loading provision sounds like some kind of permission to load things into your truck but not stay in the area after loading; so if that’s the kind of provision you (as a truck driver) have, then you’re not allowed to unload swap bodies. Though I’m not sure if that really makes much sense. (You may be more successful with this type of translator’s question on the ProZ boards or on the TCTerms section of TranslatorsCafé, which is specifically aimed at understanding and translating technical terminology.)

Comment: It should be noted that the above is clearly not referring to US trucking (since dimensions are metric).  Since trucking lingo is apt to be culture-specific, one needs to seek British/European sources of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first quote, an initial "the" has been dropped, with the meaning actually being "The boot has to be 1.10m as a minimum, as it was previously."

A little Googling seems to indicate that pass-through loading means that the container has doors at both ends, allowing loading and unloading from either end.